# How can I make a function of a member class public while the rest is private?

Tags: c++

I want to make a class like this:

```
class foo{
private:
   std::vector<DifferentClass> ClassVec1;
public:
   int addDiffClass(){...returns id in vector...};
}
```

In this class the add function returns a id and I want to make the .at or the [] operator of the vector public so that the user can access the items in the vector like normal. However I dont want the push_back function to be available to ensure that the object is actually added correctly.

How can I do that?

Comment: write a wrapper in the containing class. Since the whole internal class is hidden it will be accessed through the containing class anyway.

Comment: Just add the `at()` function to your class and get it to call the `at()` function in the private vector

Comment: @Galik Can you post this as an answer so I can flag it as solved? Also whats wrong with the post? (why the downvotes?). Its short and gets to the point. Includes an example and is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to restrict the methods available as follows.

```
class myClass {
   private:
         std::vector<DifferentClass> ClassVec1;
   public:
       DifferentClass & operator[]( size_t elem ){
           return ClassVec1[elem];
       }
}
```